# How to modify dom elements programmatically in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, anchor

I am building a reactjs application. I get html content as string.
For example:

```
  state= {elem:`<div>
          <p>...</p>
          <a href="www.twitter.com"></a>
          <h1>Heading</h1>
          <div>
            <a href="www.facebook.com"></a>
          </div>
        </div>`.}
```

I will be setting this in my dom using                         `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this._createMarkup()} />`

```
 _createMarkup = () => {
        return { __html: this.state.elem};
    };
```

Instead of directly rendering this html snippet in the dom, I need to parse it and make modifications. That is, wherever there is an anchor tag, I need to append http:// if it is not present in the href attribute. There can be multiple anchor tags in the snippet. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with React. You can do this easily using JS regex. ( But why `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` anyway ? )

Comment: @CKA with React anchor tag will not help you.Irs better to define component for above requirement

Comment: Use String.prototype.replace().

Comment: How else am I going to render html content that i receive from API? @Dane

Comment: @Dane Could you show me how I can do this using regex?

Comment: If it's HTML content, fine :) then use `replace()`. Something like `htmlstring.replace(/<a href="www/g, '<a href="http://www')`, though you have to polish it a lil bit more, consider edge cases ( when the given url doesn't start with 'www' )

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dane

Comment: But I cannot guarantee that the links will be in the format <a href="www.twitter.com", they can be <a class="some-class" href="www.twitter.com"></a>. So accessing them as strings may not be a wise idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), which is widely supported, in order to achieve that.

Here's a little snippet.

```js
const parser = new DOMParser();
const htmlText = `<div>
          <p>...</p>
          <a href="www.twitter.com">Twitter</a>
          <h1>Heading</h1>
          <div>
            <a href="www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
          </div>
        </div>`;

let content = parser.parseFromString(htmlText, "text/html");
const anchors = content.getElementsByTagName('a');


Array.from(anchors).forEach(v => {
  const href = v.getAttribute("href");

  if (!href.includes('http://')) {
    v.href = 'http://' + href;
  }
})


console.log(content.body.innerHTML); // Here it is your new string

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content.body.innerHTML}} />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the exact solution I was looking for. You are a life saver!